# How Can JavaScript Handle Large Amounts of JSON Data Quickly?

Tags: javascript, json, logic

I'm working with big JSON data for a web project. It's a lot and makes my browser slow. I need help with:

- Fast ways to use big JSON data without slowing down the browser.
- How to not use too much computer memory.
- Can I work on the data bit by bit instead of all at once?

**i have tried JSON.parse()**

Looking for simple tips or tools. Thanks!

Comment: You need to take a look at Object pooling and memory management in browser

Comment: You could break up the data and store it in a real database.

Comment: "big" is vague ... how big is the JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple tools I guess.

You can use any 3rd party JSON streaming parsers like

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json

to parse some initial chunk of data.

A comprehensive list is here:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7543#issuecomment-41970902

You could also move your fetching and parsing into a worker.

But the question is why you need such big data in the first place.